# Graphing tan in matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

if 1:
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    ax.axhline(linewidth=1.7, color="black")
    ax.axvline(linewidth=1.7, color="black")

    plt.xticks([1])
    plt.yticks([])

    ax.text(0, 1.05, 'y', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes), ha='center')
    ax.text(1.05, 0, 'x', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transAxes, ax.transData), va='center')

    for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

    x = numpy.linspace(-1, 1, 10000)
    ax.plot(x, numpy.tan(2*(x - numpy.pi/2)), linewidth=1.2, color="black")

    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

which produces this graph:
[image: graph]

As you can see, not only is the tan graph sketched, but a portion of line is added to join the asymptotic regions of the tan graph, where an asymptote would normally be.

Is there some built in way to skip that section? Or will I graph separate disjoint domains of tan that are bounded by asymptotes (if you get what I mean)?

Comment: Just for clarity: do you want to get rid of the horizontal line that connects your `-∞` and `∞` values?

Comment: @jsalonen you mean the vertical lines? If so, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something you could try: set a finite threshold and modify your function to provide non-finite values after those points. Practical code modification:

```
yy = numpy.tan(2*(x - numpy.pi/2))
threshold = 10000
yy[yy>threshold] = numpy.inf
yy[yy<-threshold] = numpy.inf
ax.plot(x, yy, linewidth=1.2, color="black")
```

Results in:

[image: Result]

Comment: For some reason I do not get the output that you get when I add your solution to my code. Do you also mean to do "yy[yy<-threshold] = numpy.inf", using an "<-" operator, rather than the "<" operator? Your solution is a very simple one though and I think it's a great idea

Comment: The operators are `>` and `<`. What versions of libs you are using? I'm running numpy 1.7.1 and matplotlib 1.2.1 on Python 2.7.4. Also you could try lowering the threshold value to test if it works as expected.

Comment: No I mean - take a look at your line 4; you use "<-"

Comment: Haha silly me.... obviously you are doing "< -threshold", here I am thinking numpy has somehow added a new operator to the Python language. BTW reducing the threshold has worked perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: Exactly that! I used two operators: `<` and `-`. `-` operator has higher precedence so it is evaluated before `<`. For details, see: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 0):

[image]This code creates a figure and one subplot for tangent function. NaN are inserted when cos(x) is tending to 0 (NaN means "Not a Number" and NaNs are not plotted or connected).
matplot-fmt-pi created by k-donn(https://pypi.org/project/matplot-fmt-pi/) used to change the formatter to make x labels and ticks correspond to multiples of π/8 in fractional format.
plot formatting (grid, legend, limits, axis) is performed as commented.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplot_fmt_pi import MultiplePi

fig, ax = plt.subplots()        # creates a figure and one subplot
x = np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.tan(x)
y[np.abs(np.cos(x)) <= np.abs(np.sin(x[1]-x[0]))] = np.nan
# This operation inserts a NaN where cos(x) is reaching 0
# NaN means "Not a Number" and NaNs are not plotted or connected
ax.plot(x, y, lw=2, color="blue", label='Tangent')
# Set up grid, legend, and limits
ax.grid(True)
ax.axhline(0, color='black', lw=.75)
ax.axvline(0, color='black', lw=.75)
ax.set_title("Trigonometric Functions")
ax.legend(frameon=False)    # remove frame legend frame
# axis formatting
ax.set_xlim(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi)
pi_manager = MultiplePi(8)          # number= ticks between 0 - pi
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(pi_manager.locator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(pi_manager.formatter())
plt.ylim(top=10)  # y axis limit values
plt.ylim(bottom=-10)
y_ticks = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
plt.yticks(y_ticks)
fig
[![enter image description here][1]][1]plt.show()
```